# How can I calculate the overall amount of detail in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm working with a library of photos, and I'd like some way of calculating a 'detail' value for each image as a whole. By detail, I mean the amount of contrasting colours, shades and edges, such that an image that's a single flat colour would have 0 detail, and a photo filled with lots of small elements would have a high detail value.

This doesn't have to be super-precise - I'd like to identify images that have a detail value higher than some threshold, and treat them differently. A reasonable guess is good enough.

I have a few ideas that might be feasible:

- Save the image as a JPG at a given size and compression level, and check the resulting file size. This basically uses the compression algorithm as the check - detailed images make large files. Seems slow, expensive, and crude, but it wouldn't require a lot of custom work.
- Sub-divide the image into a grid, sample points within each square, and compare how unique their values are. It seems like it could work, but would require a fine grid and a lot of samples in order to be useful.
- Use an edge-detecting filter like unsharp-mask: Take the original, and a copy sharpened by a known amount, then take the average colour of each. If they are very different, the filter has done a 'lot of work' and therefore the image has a lot of edges (and so a lot of detail). This seems promising, but I'm not sure if it would actually work!

Processing will be done out-of-band, so performance isn't a huge issue. If it takes a few seconds per image, that's fine. I'm using rMagick (imageMagick) and Ruby.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way?

Comment: It ultimately depends on how you want to define 'detail' but if you are okay with using edges as a metric, I think that wouldn't be difficult to implement. Simply run an edge detection algorithm (I can suggest MATLAB code to do this) and do an average on all the pixel values. An image with no edges would return a low value (theoretically zero) and a highly 'detailed' image would return a much higher average pixel value.

Comment: Hey, @mban, I've put some more thought into this, and I think your edge detection approach is the right one. If you post an answer (and some matlab or pseudocode for the steps), I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: You can get a measure of detail from the variance or standard-deviation. `convert image -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" info:` The result will be between 0 and 1. Or you can multiply by 100 to get percent.  `convert image -format "%[fx:100*standard_deviation]\n" info:`. The mean of edge content is also another measure.

Answer (score 2):

You could try measuring the entropy and see how that works for your images - it's hard to tell how well it will perform for your needs though.

You get ImageMagick to measure it like this:

```
identify -format '%[entropy]' input.jpg
```

You can also measure it using the `convert` tool like this:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:white gradient:red-blue +append -print '%[entropy]' null:
```

Or you could do, say, a Canny edge detection and then calculate the mean of the resulting black and white image which will tell you what percentage of the pixels are edges as an integer between 0-100, like this:

```
convert input.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:
12
```

As suggested by Kurt, you could also look at the number of unique colours divided by the number of pixels. which will obviously give small results for large blocks of constant colour and larger results for photograph-type images.

```
identify -format "%k different colors, %w (width), %h (height)\n" image.jpg
```

Comment: Entropy does seem promising... though the fact that it only looks at the histogram might mean that otherwise 'detailed' images have quite a low entropy value: looking at this: http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/entropy/index.php, the black and white grid has quite a low entropy even though it has a lot of visual 'detail'. I'll investigate, thanks!

Comment: On top of entropy, you could also use the number of different colors divided by the total number of pixels of the image. `identify -format "%k different colors, %w (width), %h (height)\n" my-img.jpg` will report the number of different colors, the width and the height of the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Feel free to add it to your answer, Mark.

Comment: The total number of different colours could give a 'wrong' answer (for my admittedly arbitrary definition of 'detail') - imagine a black and white line drawing (lots of detail, few colours), vs a two way colour gradient (many colours, little detail).

Answer (score 2):

I liked the edge detection suggestion -

```
convert input.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:
```

However, this has some big drawbacks.  The biggest is that the values you get are hugely dependent on the size of the image.

For reference, I am interested in using this to get an objective measure of the level of detail in Tibetan thangkas.  The price of a thangka is very dependent on the amount of time an artist takes to paint it and that, in turn, is hugely dependent on the amount of detail in the painting.  The more painstaking little details the longer it take to paint the thangka.  One thangka with a lot of detail can take over a year.  Another thangka that is the same size but has much less detail can take just a week.

To be useful, this measure has to be scaled based on the size of the photograph - it should give the same answer if you have a gigapixel photograph as if you have a megapixel photograph as long as you have enough resolution to see the smallest details in the painting.

My first pass with ImageMagick is:

```
magick convert pic.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -format "%[fx:mean*sqrt(w*h)]" info:
```

When I test with this image, it works very well.
[multi-star picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpuZ0.jpg)

I get the same value for this image when I scale it by a factor of 2 and a pretty close value when I scale it down by 10%... but the number is smaller which you should expect because some of the detail is being eliminated when you scale it down.

Unfortunately, when I try it on an actual thangka image it does not work as well:
[Actual thangka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NKYO.jpg)

When I scale this up I get very different results - by as much as a factor of 1.5.  Need to find a better measure.